# Java: Why does adding the package specification to my class cause a run-time error?

Tags: java, classpath, package

So, my code is pretty simple. Just wanted to try and create a package.

```
// /home/user1/Code/packageTest/src/myPackage/Test.java

package myPackage;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, world.");
    }
}
```

let's say this code is in some directory myPackage.

If I comment out the first line (package specification) the code runs fine, prints the message. It compiles either way, but if it compiled with the package line not commented out, it causes a run-time error.

What do I need to do to successfully make a package? I can't seem to find the right search terms to turn up a real explanation on this, only stuff about package naming conventions, why they're used to separate namespaces, bla bla bla. The next part of this experiment was going to be trying import my own packages, obviously I didn't even get that far.

Something to do with the classpath perhaps...? What and where is my "base directory"? Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what error you see with package name added?

Comment: how are you running the code, and please quote the specific errors.

Comment: Maybe you should specify the proper classpath parameter.

Comment: Are you running off of the command line? What directory are you running from?

Comment: I assume that you're calling the application using something like `java Test`?  Make sure you provide the fully qualified name of the class ie `java myPackage.Test`.  Also make sure you're compiling the class using the same package path ie `javac myPackage.Test`. Obviously all this should be done from the `/home/user1/Code/packageTest/src` context

Comment: Provide the command line you are using. Yes, this has to do with CLASSPATH, and you will find a.good introduction on the Java Tutorial web site.

Answer (score 3):

You should create the class in a java file in a directory with name `myPackage`. Then you should come out of that directory and compile it as follows

```
javac myPackage/Test.java
```

Then run it with fully-qualified-class-name (FQCN) as follows:

```
java myPackage.Test
```

E.g.

```
C:\Temp\test1>type myPackage\Test.java
package myPackage;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, world.");
    }
}
C:\Temp\test1>javac myPackage/Test.java

C:\Temp\test1>java myPackage.Test
Hello, world.

C:\Temp\test1>
```